# Java class delimiter

Tags: java, классы, split

Всем привет. Я относительно недавно начал изучать Java. И есть некоторые затруднения. Вот условия задачи что бы быть в курсе моего вопроса.

1. Модифицировать предыдущую работу которая была связана с **сортировкой по количеству букв**, следующим образом: для букв,слов, предложений, знаков препинания и текста создать отдельные классы. Слово должно состоять из массива букв, предложения из массива слов и знаков препинания, текст из массива предложений. Заменить последовательность табуляций и пробелов одним пробелом.
2. Создать класс, который состоит из исполнительного метода, выполняет описанную действие с предыдущей работы, но в качестве типов использует созданные классы. Необходимо обработать все исключительные ситуации, которые могут возникнуть во время выполнение кода. Все переменные должны быть описаны и значение их заданные в исполнительном методе.

У меня практически все готово кроме знаков препинания. Я вот думаю, если создать класс допустим `Delimiter` и там у меня есть метод и String'овое поле `StringDelimiter` мне придется использовать `split();` такой вот вопрос как мне потом вернуть их обратно когда буду вызывать припустим некий метод `print()` в том же классе к примеру? Да кстати **нельзя использовать коллекции**. Заранее благодарен.

Собственно мой код

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Sentences {
    private String wordSt, replace;

    public Sentences() { }
    public Sentences(String wordSt) {
        this.wordSt = wordSt;
        String[] words = wordSt.split(" ");
        Word wrd = new Word();
        for(String word : words) {
            wrd.enter_word(word);
        }
    }
}

class PlaceSpaces {
   private String stroke, replace;
   public void space_replacing(String stroke) {
       replace = stroke.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
       System.out.print(replace);
   }
}

class Word {
   private String letters;
   public void enter_word(String input) {
       int[] symbols = new int[1000];

       for (byte current : input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
           symbols[current]++;

       java.lang.StringBuilder builder = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
       for (int count = 1; count < input.length(); count++)
           for (char charCode = 0; charCode < symbols.length; charCode++)
              if (symbols[charCode] == count)
                 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) builder.append(charCode);
       String ss = builder.toString();
       PlaceSpaces ps = new PlaceSpaces();
       ps.space_replacing(ss);
     //System.out.print(builder.toString());
   }
}


public class Laba4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        Sentences word = new Sentences();
//        word.sort();
//        Word wrd = new Word();
//        wrd.word();
//        Word wrd = new Word();
//        wrd.enter_word("hhhhheeelllo     aaaaaabb");
          Sentences st = new Sentences("hhhhheeelllo     aaaaaabb");
        //st.showWord();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все я понял как мне нужно добавить это. Естественно это не то что я ожидал но все таки)

```
class Separator {
    private final static String SEPARATORS = new String(",. \\t!\\\";:'-");
    public boolean isSeparator(String stroke) {
        for( int i=0; i < stroke.length(); i++ ) {
            if(SEPARATORS.indexOf(stroke.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```